# How can I get how many ocurrences are of an event over the event's own mean?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with grades:

```
name   grade
peter  10
paul    8
mary    7
peter   6
mary   10
paul    5
paul    7
paul    6
mary    2
```

I would like to count how many grades does each of one have above their own mean.

For example, Peter has two grades, so Peter's mean is 8. Mary has 3 grades, but only 2 are above her own mean. Paul, has 4 grades, but only 2 are above his own mean. I would like to get as result something like:

```
name  count
peter   1
mary    2
paul    2
```

I tried to do this using subqueries or adding a condition inside a count() column, but I usually get an error that tells me that my subquery returns more than 1 result. How can I achieve this?

Here is one of my attempts:

```
with staging as (
select name, count(*) as total,MAX(grade) as max_g, MIN(grade) as min_g, AVG(grade) as avg, STD(grade) as std
from students
where course = 'stats'
group by name)

select name,count(IF(grade > (select avg from staging),1,0)) as grades_over_mean from students
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query. And note that tables in an RDBMS normally have a PRIMARY KEY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select s.*,
       sum(grade > avg_grade) as num_above_average
from (select s.*,
             avg(grade) over (partition by name) as avg_grade
      from students s
     ) s;
```